# angular2 http resolve promise

Tags: angular, promise, angular-routing

good evening fellas

I'm trying to get into angular2 and got a problem that keeps me from going on.

Service:

```
  getProject(id: number): any {
    var url = this.ProjectsUrl + '/'+ id;
     return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.json().data as Project);
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Component:

```
  getProject(id:number){
       this.projectService
        .getProject(id)
        .then(project => this.project = project); 
  }
```

ngOnInit()

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getCustomers();
      console.log('b4 getProj')
      this.getProject(+params["id"]);
      console.log('after getProj')
     });
  }
```

Output:

```
b4 getProj
after getProj
Object { Project }
```

I cant figure out why the promise wont get resolved? Any tips?

Comment: Why do you think something doesn't get resolved?

Answer (score 1):

One good thing with Angular2 is its support to Observables in place of Promises.

Just in case if you want to use Observables in place of Promises then below code can be used:

Service:

```
 getProject(id: number): any {
    var url = this.ProjectsUrl + '/'+ id;
     return this.http.get(url)
      .map(response => {
        response.json().data as Project;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Component:

```
  getProject(id:number){
           this.projectService
            .getProject(id)
            .subscribe(project => {
             this.project = project
           }); 
        }
```

I hope this helps.

Just remember to add following declaration in your service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your anwser. I guess I need to get the difference of those two methods before I proceed.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
  getProject(id:number){
    return this.projectService // <<<=== added return
        .getProject(id)
        .then(project => this.project = project); 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getCustomers();
      console.log('b4 getProj')
      this.getProject(+params["id"])
      .then(_ => console.log('after getProj')); // <<<=== changed
     });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Günter.  I'm going to try this out tomorrow for sure. But I wonder why the snippet I posted works for every other http-Request but this?!

Comment: This is just a guess. I wasn't able to figure out from your question, what the problem is.